# Making concentric circles in GIMP

Tags: image-manipulation, gimp

I have a single layer image that is 480px square, which I am created with GIMP (it is blank). How can I make:

1. Three concentric circles (the center being at 240,240 px) with radii 240, 180, and 60.
2. Impose a 120px square .png image into the smallest circle, with the center of the circle matching 60,60 px in the image, and cut of the parts of the image that don't fit in the circle.
3. Type in some text and have it wrap around in a circle between the outermost and middle circles.

Honestly, this is the only time I plan to use this software, and it is very confusing to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ellipse select tool (E) to select a circle of your desire, say 360px width/height. Fill the selection with foreground color (Menu -> Edit -> Fill with FG Color). Reduce the selection by i.e. 2px (Menu -> Select -> shrink...). Fill the shrinked selection with background color (Menu -> Edit -> Fill with BG Color)

Thats the way to create circles in gimp.

Answer (score 0):

This is an hack to get **several concentric** circles without the burden of manually making each of them:

Make some sort of rectangular shape (a linear gradient works well too).
Then use from the menu Filters the waves (waves should be in the *distort* subset of filters) with max amplitude. Use the period to tune the size of the circles.

Comment: Details? @cmks describes how to perform his solution.